# QCD Trace Anomaly and Mass

Tags: mass, quantum-chromodynamics, quantum-anomalies, trace

In the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.00827) in equations 4 and 5, some of the mass of the nucleons comes from the "trace anomaly" of the QCD energy-momentum tensor (as described in the paragraph following these equations). Is there a simple physical interpretation of where this mass comes from? Such as the other contributions coming from quark mass and Parton kinetic energy.

Comment: Please type out the specific equations you are referring to. Links can change with time and become useless.

Comment: The paper makes ample references to the trace anomaly. It is the piece "purely" due to QM, which vanishes as $\hbar \to 0$, so it is due to glue and its quantum interactions and fluctuations.  It is at the heart of the RG. Have you read up on the [trace anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_anomaly#QCD)?